# "@" Character Not sending on my feed message with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

When sending a  message to my Profile page Or fun page Via the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

The "@" character is not showing in the message or caption ..

```
$gonder=$facebook->api('/'.$kid.'/feed','POST',
  array(
    'link'=>'www.facebook.com',
    'message'=>'Merhaba @ cracter not show',
    'name'=>'test message',
    'description'=>'Kimler Bizimle'
));
```

Comment: Note: your post was edited, however the person editing it also added the `access_token` part and changed the name of one of your variables. If this was in error, edit those parts.

Comment: @nic - please don't edit code blocks in peoples questions. Rather leave a comment and let the original asker change the code. The other changes (such as spelling and grammar are fine though).

Comment: I did not edit anything in the code block

Comment: @nic - the revision history of the post [seems to say otherwise](http://i.imgur.com/QTjqmqG.png)...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because at one stage Facebook would parse that sign and use it to tag users much like is possible when using the normal site. I'm not 100% sure if this parsing is still happening at the API level though.

You might want to try and escape that `@` character. Perhaps this will make Facebook ignore it's (once) special meaning.

You have a few options for escaping - one or more of these methods might be what you need -

1. Backslash - `'message'=>'Merhaba \@ cracter not show'`
2. URL Encoding - `'message'=>'Merhaba %40 cracter not show'`
3. HTML code - `'message'=>'Merhaba &#64; cracter not show'`

Comment: Thanks **@Lix** but not working all ways to sending "@" caracter on facebook :(
'
\@ ---->  Result On Facebook -- >  \
%40 --->  Result On Facebook -->  %40
&#64;-->  Result On Facebook --> &#64;  
All Shown like text on facebook But Not Show "@" Caracter 

$message=urlencode($message); --> Result --> %40+caracter+not+show '